# AIX run time error: Symbol __dbargs (number 191) is not exported from dependent

Tags: c, linker, aix, xlc

I am getting errors when I try to run my executable together with my shared library on AIX:

```
    Symbol __dbargs (number 191) is not exported from dependent
      module /opt/CA/SharedComponents/lib/libcfOSServices.a.
    Symbol __dbsubc (number 192) is not exported from dependent
      module /opt/CA/SharedComponents/lib/libcfOSServices.a.
    Symbol __dbsubg (number 193) is not exported from dependent
      module /opt/CA/SharedComponents/lib/libcfOSServices.a.
    Symbol __dbsubn (number 194) is not exported from dependent
      module /opt/CA/SharedComponents/lib/libcfOSServices.a.
```

According to my Google searches it could be remedied by removing the `-g` option during compilation and linking. But I would rather keep the debugging info there. Is it possible? <strike>I have even tried to add `-lg`, as some of my search results have suggested. It did not help either.</strike>

**UPDATE**

It turns adding explicit `-lg` does help.

Comment: Did you try without `-g` ? Just to be sure it's the problem.

Comment: I am not sure if I can control that. I can control that in my component but not for the `libcfOSServices.a` file.

Comment: This http://www.linuxmisc.com/11-unix-aix/5536d93caf16ec9c.htm explains some things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns adding explicit `-lg` does help.